Why cannot I create a new Project inside Bitbucket?
I need to FORK a project from GitHub inside Bitbucket. I was told by our IT admin that he defined me as an Admin inside our Bitbucket.
So, since I need to fork a new GitHub repository, I think that I will need to create a new Project inside Bitbucket; but when I login inside our Bitbucket and I access the Projects tab I did not find any option to create a new Project:

Also no options to create new repository;

I can only create Snippet. So, what is the issue? Is it a permission?

I don't think this is a git question.

@eftshift0 yes removed the tag, seems it is by wrong

They should double check which groups you are in and that they give permissions to create a project
